# How to generate a POST request with file upload and other fields from asp.net app?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could someone please give me a short example of how to upload a file and send multiple text fields in a single POST request from ASP.NET app?

For example, from my asp.net app that runs on an in-house server, I'd like to upload a file along with 2 text fields (e.g. name, date) to another server using a POST request.  I think that I need to use WebClient but I'm not quite sure how to combine multiple fields with file upload in a single request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A good AJAX option would be to send a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) object (note: incompatible with IE < 10), which you could then POST to your .NET backend, a la...

//Initialize new instance of form data
    var uploadData = new FormData();

```
//Get parameters 
uploadData.append("ID", eID);
uploadData.append("adPhoto", theImage);
uploadData.append("field2", field2);

//Make AJAX call 
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", Defaults.PhotoUploadService);
xhr.send(uploadData);
```

On the backend...

```
public static void UploadFile() {

int ID = Context.Request.Params["ID"];
string field = Convert.ToInt32(Context.Request.Params["field"]);

//Get your photo here
byte[] fileData = null;
HttpPostedFile postedFile = Context.Request.Files["adPhoto"];

using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream))
      {
      fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Context.Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
      }

// Do whatever you have to do at this point...

}
```

Makes sense? Hope that helps and is a good start!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, this is not exactly what I'm after.  I'd like to execute your Ajax sample from my ASP.NET app on the server side.  I suspect that I'd need to use HttpRequest in a similar way you used Ajax XMLHttpRequest.  That is, if I only could translate your Ajax sample to a C#/ASP.NET server code I'd be OK.